# JavaScript: What's the difference between a positive look ahead and a non-capturing group?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I get it right then a positive look ahead ( ?= ) as well a non-capturing group ( ?: ) are used for to excluse a part of the string in the final match-results.

**What is the difference between the a lookahead and a non-capturing group?**

Can anyone explain? Preferable with an easy understandable example?

Comment: They both don't exclude a part. A lookahead just looks forward to match/fail a pattern, but afterwards the cursor is still in the same position. A non-capturing group matches normally, but doesn't store it's match into a group that you could later refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive look ahead is a zero width assertion. This means that it will not consume an input, e.g. in

```
/(?=.)./
```

the `(?=.)` part will match with the first characters of the string and the `.` will match with the same character. On the other hand

```
/(?:.)./
```

the `(?:.)` part will match with the first characters of the string (just like before) but the `.` will match with the second character because the first character will have been consumed by the parentheses.

Comment: Awesome. I got it ! :) Thanks a lot.